# How to create an augmented AFL fuzzer which skips certain seeds?

Tags: python, c, fuzzing, fuzzer, american-fuzzy-lop

I am a master's student working on replicating the results of the paper : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/not-all-bytes-are-equal-neural-byte-sieve-for-fuzzing/

I want to create an augmented fuzzer which rejects the modifications to seeds which it finds not useful. Any help in achieving this will be very much helpful.

I have created a simple python function for the augmented fuzzer. To test the implementation, I took the trivial "deadbeef" program and wrote the python function such that whenever the seed is modified to "deadbeef", the function sends a "not useful" return to the 'common_fuzz_stuff()' function of the AFL-fuzz code. It should mean that the fuzzer should not be able to find the crash. But it still is able to find the crash and I'm not able to determine where I have gone wrong.

Here is the python function for AFL:

```
 def check_useful(seed):

  my_string = str.encode('deadbeef')

  file = open(seed, 'rb')

  value = file.read()


  if (value == my_string):

    print('[*] Crash Found!')

    return True


 else:

   return False
```

And here is the afl-fuzz.c code snippet:

```
/* Write a modified test case, run program, process results. Handle

error conditions, returning 1 if it's time to bail out. This is

a helper function for fuzz_one(). */


EXP_ST u8 common_fuzz_stuff(char** argv, u8* out_buf, u32 len) {


if (PyCallable_Check(pFuncCheckModel)){


pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);

PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyUnicode_FromString(queue_cur->fname));

pFuncReturn = PyObject_CallObject(pFuncCheckModel, pArgs);

if (PyObject_IsTrue(pFuncReturn)){

skip_requested = 1;

return 1;

}

} else

{

PyErr_Print();

}
```

How is my program still able to find the crash even if the return value is 1 from the common_fuzz_stuff() function for the seed "deadbeef"?

Comment: Have you looked at their code repository? https://github.com/arvindrao7589/augmented-afl-fuzz

Comment: Hello Nick, yes I have looked at it. The link you have just contains the original afl code

Comment: @VineethBharadwaj Thank you for posting this. Have you put your code somewhere online? If not, could you do so? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
I had to send `out_file` to the Python function instead of `queue_cur->fname`.

```
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyUnicode_FromString(out_file));
```

Also `skip_requested = 1;` in the above code is redundant.

Now the fuzzer will run and will not find the crash

Answer (score 0):

In case your decision whether this input is useful or not depends **only on the input itself** (not the mutation), as far as I understand, you could use the `experimental/post_library` stuff. The documentation is included in the example post_library and contains a note, that *this is probably not what you want* -- not you for your specific need, this is approximate cite from that documentation. :)

On the other hand, this single-function-API description contains the following:

```
2) If you want to skip this test case altogether and have AFL generate a
   new one, return NULL. Use this sparingly - it's faster than running
   the target program with patently useless inputs, but still wastes CPU
   time.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I solved my problem and answered it. I have to use 'out_file' instead of 'queue_cur->fname' to reject a seed from being executed :)